# Vue.js recursive and editable components

Tags: vue.js, recursion, vuex, vuedraggable

I am working on a HTML builder GUI in vue.js, and I'm stuck with recursive component's update.

I have two drag&drops in my main file Home.vue, one listing available components (title, question, text...), the other one where you add&clone those components. This drag area also is draggable for its inner components (a question may lead to an other question, or text, etc.). I use vue-draggable library and a nested-draggable recursive component to achieve this.

My problem is that each component is editable, and I simply don't know how to save those changes. Since I'm passing tree data as a prop, I can't change it in the child, and I'm not sure about an $emit to the parent since the component is recursive...
All the examples I can find are about simple trees with fix data.

What would be the best way to achieve this ? Is Vuex a good idea (if yes, is there an example somewhere cause I don't know where to begin) ?

Home.vue

```
    <script>
    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        components: {
            draggable,
            nestedDraggable
        },
        data() {
            return {
                listDraggable: [
                    {
                        "name": "Title",
                        "component": "inputTitle", // Component name that will be load 
                        "id": 0,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Question",
                        "component": "inputQuestion",
                        "id": 1,
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Text",
                        "component": "inputText",
                        "id": 2,
                    }
                ],
                treeList: [],
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<template>
    <v-row justify="center">
        <v-col cols="2">
            <h3>Components</h3>
            <v-card class="componentList">
                <v-card-text>
                    <draggable
                            class="dragArea list-group"
                            :list="listDraggable"
                            :group="{ name: 'components', pull: 'clone', put: false }">
                        <div class="list-group-item" v-for="element in listDraggable">
                            {{ element.name }}
                        </div>
                    </draggable>
                </v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="8">
            <h3>Drag & drop</h3>
            <nested-draggable class="dragArea list-group" group="components" :tree="treeList">
            </nested-draggable>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

NestedDraggable.vue

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <draggable class="dragArea list-group" :list="tree" group="components">
            <div class="list-group-item" v-for="el in tree" :key="el.id">
                <!-- Dynamic component depending on component property -->
                <component :is="el.component" :data="el"></component>
                <nested-draggable :tree="el.nodes"/>
            </div>
        </draggable>
    </div>
</template>
```

For example a component inputTitle.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'inputTitle',
        props: ['data']
    }
</script>

<template>
    <v-row dense justify="space-around">
        <v-col cols="6">
            <!-- how can I bind/save the entered title ? --> 
            <v-text-field placeholder="Enter a title">{{data.title}}</v-text-field>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

Comment: Sure, Vuex is a good idea for any global state, and for recursive components to avoid emit chains.  I would start at the [official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: I've already worked with Vuex so I know how it works, but in this particular scenario I don't know how to implement it : a treeData in the store sure, probably paths of each node to get/update those nodes. But when I drag from component list to the second one, it has to update a list : which list if not a direct treeList as a data in Home.vue ? How should I get the tree in the root component ? Sorry it may not be clear but it shows how confused I am about this...

Comment: `Vue-draggable` has an [example](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/nested-with-vmodel) using Vuex.  [Code](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/nested-with-vmodel.vue) and [Store](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/nested/nested-store.js).  You can grab their two display helper components as well.  [1](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/nested/nested-test.vue) and [2](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/infra/raw-displayer.vue)

Comment: The example works, I added an input in each element (both template and in store definition) and the value seams to be well saved in vuex store but to do so, I used v-model : <v-text-field v-model="el.label"></v-text-field> (label being passed in props with elements), but I thought props should not be directly modified. Is this a good practice ?

Comment: I can't put up a comprehensive answer right now, but the 2 main ways to do this are 1) a [computed setter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#two-way-computed-property)-- in this case your `get` will return the prop.  Or, 2) Clone the prop into a `data` item first, use that item in the `v-model`, then listen on the `@change` / `@input` events from the textbox and dispatch the clone to the store from the listener.